# What is the PHP equivalent of JavaScript spread syntax for constructing an array?

Tags: javascript, php

Asked already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936104/what-is-the-error-when-converting-functions-from-ruby-to-js) about converting functions from Ruby to JS, and now I'm trying to implement with JS to PHP, but something does not work, tell me what I'm missing?

The code on JS:

```js
function transpose(a) {
    return a.length === 0 ? a : a[0].map((col, i) => a.map((row) => row[i]))
}

function f(a) {
    return a.length === 0 ? [] : [...a.shift(), ...f(transpose(a).reverse())];
} 

console.log(f([[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]))
```

In PHP do so:

```
function transpose($array) 
{
    if (count($array) === 0) return $array;

    foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $colkey => $col)
        {
            $out[$colkey][$rowkey] = $col;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

function f($a)
{
    return (count($a) === 0) 
    ? [] 
    : [
        array_shift(...$a), 
        f(array_reverse(transpose(...$a)))
    ];
}

print_r(f([[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,5],[9,8,7,6]]));
```

Is there a problem? Errors:

> Warning: array_shift() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in [...][...] on line 24
>
> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...][...] on line 10
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...][...] on line 10
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...][...] on line 10
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...][...] on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: out in [...][...] on line 16
>
> Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in [...][...] on line 25
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in [...][...] on line 21

Comment: Can you please add some more details about what you mean by "something does not work"?

Comment: You can't do that.  As PHP is precompiled and JS is post compiled, you cannot do PHP from the JS side.

Comment: `array_shift(...$a)` should be `...array_shift($a)` to be equivalent to the JS.

Comment: @Forbs, so it's not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `...` operator in the PHP version. You just need to merge the shifted row with the result of the recursive call.

```
function f($a)
{
    return (count($a) === 0) 
    ? [] 
    : array_merge(
        array_shift($a), 
        f(array_reverse(transpose($a)))
    );
}
```

---

```
array_merge(array_shift($a), f(array_reverse(transpose($a))))
```

is the same thing that's happening here:

```
[...a.shift(), ...f(transpose(a).reverse())]
```

`...` expands the elements of the array in JS. It works similarly in PHP, but here it is only valid in function definitions or calls.

Answer (score 3):

You have your `...` (AKA "splat") operators in a different place in the PHP than the JS.

Also, prior to PHP 7.4 the splat operator can't be used in array literals, only in function calls. The use in the `f()` function is equivalent to `array_merge()`.

```
function f($a)
{
    return (count($a) === 0) 
    ? [] 
    : array_merge(
        array_shift($a), 
        f(array_reverse(transpose($a)))
    );
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/A06Y8z)

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS)`

Comment: You can't use `...` in array literals, so I changed to a function call.

Comment: php 7.4 now supports unpacking inside arrays. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks, I've added the caveat about 7.4 to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `array_shift` has too many parameters ..  All you need is the `$a` Same with `array_reverse`

```
<?php
function transpose($array)
{
    if (count($array) === 0) return $array;

    foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $colkey => $col)
        {
            $out[$colkey][$rowkey] = $col;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

function f($a)
{
    return (count($a) === 0)
    ? []
    : [
        array_shift($a),
        f(array_reverse(transpose($a)))
    ];
}

print_r(f([[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,5],[9,8,7,6]]));
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 7
                            [1] => 8
                            [2] => 9
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 10
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 11
                                            [1] => 12
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This result isn't the same as the JavaScript version.

Comment: It's supposed to return a flat array, not heavily nested.